# No results once implementing an analyzer in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am needing to ignore the apostrophe with indexed results so that searching for "Johns potato" will show results for "John's potato"

I was able to get the analyzer accepted but now I return no search results. Does anyone see something obvious that I am missing?

```
$params = [
    'index' => $index,
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 5,
            'number_of_replicas' => 2,
            'analysis' => [
                "analyzer" => [
                    "my_analyzer" => [
                        "tokenizer" => "keyword",
                        "char_filter" => [
                            "my_char_filter"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "char_filter" => [
                    "my_char_filter" => [
                        "type" => "mapping",
                        "mappings" => [
                            "' => "
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            $type => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'analyzer' => 'my_analyzer'
                    ],
                    'content' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'analyzer' => 'my_analyzer'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I did find out that removing the analyzer from my field mappings allowed results to reappear, but I get no results the second I add the analyzer.

Here's an example query that I make.

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "apples",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "terms": {
            "site_id": [
              "1351",
              "1349"
            ]
          }
        },
        "must_not": [
          {
            "match": {
              "visible": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "locked": "true"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query w/o the must_not clause?  I'm guessing visible and locked should be indexed as `keywords` and search with `terms` instead of `text`/`match`.  You probably don't want them analyzed.

Comment: I'm doing basic queries in Postman to test it. (Query->term->title: apples) and have no results unless I do apple's.

Comment: term queries are exact match.  You need to do a match query against a text field

Comment: I've been doing Match queries for a while now and have tried possessive_english stemmers, english analyzers, and that customer analyzer above. Nothing has worked so far. I can't even _analyze my index because it says analyzer isn't found. Might be something wrong with how I set it. I'm on 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you really want, is to use the `english` analyzer that is provided.  The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which is the default will tokenize on whitespace and some punctuation, but will leave apostrophes alone.  The [english analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) can stem and remove stop words since the language is known.

Here is the standard analyzer's output, where you can see "john's":

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "John's potato"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "john's",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "potato",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the english analyzer where you can see the **'s** is removed.  The stemming will allow "John's", "Johns", and "John" to all match the document.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "english",
  "text": "John's potato"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "john",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "potato",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with my must->multi_match. Should I be using a different method to query?

Comment: Should work.  I would have to see your specific query probably to give you more specific advice.

Comment: I added a query to the main post. Thank you for your help. edit: Also want to add that I am doing raw JSON queries in postman and leaving out the apostrophe still does not show results.